# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, vite

Использую сборщик `Vite`. Запускаю собранную, `production` версию при помощи `LiveServer`
Выдает данную ошибку в консоли

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Так выглядит файл `main.js`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import components from '@/components/UI'

import './assets/sass/style.sass'

const app = createApp(App)

components.forEach(component => {
    app.component(component.name, component)
})

app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

А так же, ошибки при загрузке сторонних `CSS` файлов

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5500/css/bootstrap-grid.css' because 
its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME 
checking is enabled.
```

Так выглядит `HTML` файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/donutChart.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Скорее всего из-за этой строки "import components from '@/components/UI'", судя по ошибке

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае, ошибка решилась таким образом, я запустил на сервере `Flask` и все прекрасно работает. А `LiveServer` не подошел.